# can members have multiple registration using the same password?

Tags: plugin-development

I have two membership levels e.g MYE 1 and MYE II. I am using wishlish plugin.

When a person enrolls in MYE I and then later enrolls in MYE II - they are currently blocked from using the same email address - most people only hve 1 email address that they like doing business in - Can we PLEASE allow them to use the same UN and email address and just a different PW for the 2 different programs?

How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the wishlist plugin is but I think the best way to accomplish this may be to use custom user metadata.

Such as adding "enrolled_in" to the meta_data then check for the value.

```
<?php if is_user_logged_in(){
global $user_ID;
$member_level = get_user_meta($user_ID, "member_level", true);

    //just mye1
    if($member_level == mye1){
       //Show mye1 content
    }
    //just mye2
    else if($member_level == mye2)
     //show mye2 content
    }
    //both mye1 and mye2
    else if ($member_level == mye1 && $member_level == mye2){

    //show both content
      }
        //not a member
      else{
        //logged in but not member you fail at life
      }
    }
?>
```

see: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-metadata/ and http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-user-meta/ for a few plugins

Answer (score 0):

Are we discussing a specific plugin? Does it use standard WP signup?

I don't see how usernames/emails could function that way within WP. WP needs to distinguish between individuals. Especially in regards to user levels, if WP can't distinguish, it opens the doors to all sorts of conflicts and security isues.

If someone picked my username and email, would they suddenly be an admin? How would WP distinguish posts?

If you are discussing a certain plugin, maybe accomodations can happen through that, but this couldn't work, or be a good idea at all within WP itself